# Citrix XenApp - Publish application installed in AppData Local

Tags: windows-server-2016, citrix, xenapp, webex

I have a  Citrix XenApp environment with several applications, all installed in the same Windows Server 2016 golden image. I am now trying to publish [Cisco Webex Teams (former Cisco Spark)](https://www.webex.com/downloads.html), but this application installs on `AppData\Local`.

The only article I found on this is [CTX221747](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX221747) that applies to Microsoft  Windows 7 desktops and Unidesk (Citrix App Layer). This article presents two alternative suggestions:

- During installation point to another directory (`C:\Program Files`)
- After installation copy everything from the install folder to another directory (`C:\Program Files`)

I tried both, without success. There is no request for an install directory during the installation, and after copy, the application does not open.

Any suggestion, or just another step, on how to solve this?

Ps: I know this is a simplistic view of applications on Windows, but at least for Cisco Spark I checked and could not find any Services or Drivers used that could cause complications.

Answer (score 2):

You can *force* the install to another directory by using syntax: `msiexec /i CiscoSpark_x86.msi TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files" ALLUSERS=1`.  Depending on which WebEx TAC engineer you ask, using this setting is either supported or it is not - but it definitely works.

In past testing I've observed that during an automatic update (that the client initiates, found no way to disable yet) it attempts to install back to AppData\Local however.  This new version gets used at next launch.  Updates seem to be dropping every few weeks right now.  In the past it was much more frequent.

Since XenApp tends to dump AppData\Local at logoff, this may not be a huge problem for your environment, but obviously implies that you will need to keep a constant eye on version updates to prevent undue repeated upgrade downloads from your user base.  You can monitor their download URL for changes easily enough though.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use ORCA to change the destination directory in the package. (Follow those [step](http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/downloading-installing-and-using-ms-orca) to download it, as it's in the Windows SDK -> Win32 Development Tools)

A example [there](https://4sysops.com/archives/edit-an-msi-file-with-the-orca-msi-editor/) of someone that did it used ORCA with WebEx.

My only question is, if an ActiveX, do you publish Internet Explorer too or only some application ?

As it can leverage your xenapp to publish WebEx by AppV (as XenApp fully support AppV), the rendering would be done on the end-user device, not the xenapp directly. Some example step [there](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98146311-1266-4e47-b245-904572db9185/problem-sequencing-ie-addon-cisco-webex?forum=mdopappv) to create the sequence.